# Hadoop Configuration Object read XML

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have an XML file containing some name and values that I want to read from in my Spark application. How do I use the Hadoop Configuration to read in these values and use them in my code?

I tried uploading the XML file to HDFS , but I'm not sure what the key is supposed to be when I used conf.get()

Comment: what does the xml file looks like ?

Comment: Is it one of the hadoop default xml configuration files or some random xml that you want to read and use in your spark job? If it's the latter, you should probably use `scala.xml`, it's nice and clean

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to include these lines to your code:

```
val conf = new Configuration()
conf.addResource(new Path(<path-to-file>))
```